# How to disable TinyMCE's textarea

Tags: jquery, tinymce, textarea

I've tried all of the following:

```
$(#"tbxNote").attr("disabled", "disabled"); ////doesn't work
$(#"tbxNote").attr("disabled", "true"); //doesn't work either :)

tinyMCE.init( mode: "none" ); //throws an error
```

This is how I'm loading TinyMCE:

```
//load tinymce plugin
$('#tbxNote').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url: '/common/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

    // General options
    theme: "advanced",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "link,unlink",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "", //important
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "", //important
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: false,

    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onClick.add(function (ed) {
            //ed.windowManager.alert('User clicked the editor.');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you just need it to be readonly or do you want the "disabled" style?

Comment: Readonly is fine, but I then need to enable it using jQuery.

I get tinyMCE is not defined in most cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `readonly : true` to your params.

Comment: Okay, that worked. But how would I then re-enable the textarea?

Comment: Try something like this: `<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('contentReadOnly');return false;">Readonly</a>`