# how to disable tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, javascript

I want to disable tinymce editor using Javascript.  Actually, I have two radio buttons: 1) `On` & 2) `Off`.

When the user selects the `Off` radio button, my tinymce editor should be `readonly/disabled` & when the user selects the `On` radio button, my tinymce editor should be `enabled`.

How can I achieve that?

EDITED:- (As it is not working in IE8)

```
tinyMCE.init({
    force_p_newlines : false,
    force_br_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : false,
    convert_newlines_to_brs: false,
    // Not to add br elements.
    remove_linebreaks : true,

    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "safari",
    convert_urls : false,
    width : "560",
    height : "15",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontselect,fontsizeselect, separator, bold,italic,underline,separator,forecolor,backcolor,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",

    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src| border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name], hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]"
});
```

This code is used to disable:

```
function tinymce_state(id, disable){
    var state = (disable==true)? 'Off' : 'On'
    tinymce.get(id).getDoc().designMode = state;
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('fontselect').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('fontsizeselect').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('bold').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('italic').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('underline').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('forecolor').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('backcolor').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('justifyleft').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('justifycenter').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('justifyright').setDisabled(disable);
    tinymce.get(id).controlManager.get('justifyfull').setDisabled(disable);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the other question about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455525/how-to-disable-tinymces-textarea

Comment: for 4.3.13 this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881812/make-readonly-disable-tinymce-textarea/35982854#35982854

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use the following to block input in the editor:

```
// blockeditor input
tinymce.get('editor_id').getDoc().designMode = 'Off'; // switches editable off

// turn it on again
tinymce.get('editor_id').getDoc().designMode = 'On'; // switches editable on
```

You still need to find a way to block the tinymce UI. You could deactivate EACH control you have loaded (in the init function) using a line for EACH one of them

```
// example control bold
tinymce.get('editor_id').controlManager.get('bold').setDisabled(true);

// turn it on again
tinymce.get('editor_id').controlManager.get('bold').setDisabled(false);
```

**EDIT:**

You could change the contenteditable property of your rtes iframe body.
Downside will be that you will have to disable the tinymce UI  (buttons) seperatly

```
// disable contenteditable
tinymce.get('editor_id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');

// enable contenteditable
tinymce.get('editor_id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
```

Comment: wow gr8 stuff dear........it works for me ........but i not marked it as accepted yet as there may be easier way to disable/enable tinymce Editor as well as UI..........neway thanx a million Thariama.......

Comment: i would like to know too if there is an easier method (but there might be none)

Comment: It doesn't work for TinyMCE 3.4.5.  The designMode property is already equal to "off"; changing it back and forth from "on" to "off" a few times has no effect.

Comment: you are using which browser(s)? i edited my post showing another way

Comment: I just check in IE8 and it gives me weird issue. My current page is get loaded into the editor.This happens only in IE8.When i check using IE Development Tool and it gives me error "object is undefined or null " @ tinymce.get

Comment: you will have to replace 'editor_id' with the id of your textarea/html element. could you post your tinymce config, this could help too?

Comment: @Thariama:- check my code EDITED:- (As it is not working in IE8) in question

Comment: @Thariama: Yes, there is only one editor.........and it works fine on all the browsers but IE8

Comment: in this case we need to find out what goes wrong in IE to find a workaround. can you find the line where the error occurs? if tinymce.get is the problem here (what i don't think is) you can use tinymce.editors[0] then instead

Comment: Great stuff. Contenteditable works great except in IE8. Any idea why? For now the only way I have found to disable the editor in IE8 is using a glass panel (opacity 0) above the editor to capture all events.

Comment: for 4.3.13 this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881812/make-readonly-disable-tinymce-textarea/35982854#35982854

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the collection of editors has two type of ID, the numeric ID (0,1, ... n) and an alpha ID (Testing1, testing2, ... xyx)
the commands in the code snippet only work with the aplha-based ID e.g. "Testing1"

I have twelve tinyMCE version 4.1.5 editors in my project and can disable all of them with this code:

```
for (editor_id in tinyMCE.editors) { 
    if (editor_id.length > 2) { //there are twelve editors in my project so ignore two-digit IDs
        tinyMCE.editors[editor_id].getBody().setAttribute('readonly', '1');
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, editor_id);
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, editor_id);
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, editor_id);
        tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, editor_id);
    }
}
```

This site helped me figure it out:  http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/javascript/tinymce_jquery_ajax_form

Answer (score 2):

To disable the editor use:
tinymce.activeEditor.mode.set('readonly');

To enable the editor use:
tinymce.activeEditor.mode.set('design');

Tested on version 5.x

Answer (score 1):

You can cover with a white div opacity .7 and higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in 3.x the option

editor_deselector : "no_mce",

to disabled (so give the textarea the css class no_mce). You can toggle the CSS Class with jQuery for example.

In 4.x you can use  the option

selector:'textarea.not(.no_mce)'

Hope that helps.

(Oviously you can change the CSS Class to whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

For old 3 ver you can use:

> tinyMCE.getInstanceById(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id).getBody().classList.add("mceNonEditable");